# Spyder - how to exclude files from projects?

Tags: spyder, projects-and-solutions

I am using Spyder 4.0 beta 4. I would like to know how to exclude files (__pycache__, source control files, etc.) from projects using any kind of text pattern. Under Tools > Preferences > Files, I tried unchecking the box for "Show all files", and it had no effect, even after restarting Spyder and creating a fresh project. Is there any way to exclude or ignore file name patterns in Spyder projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) I think there's no such option right now. Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), so we don't forget to do it before the final release of Spyder 4.